# Custom field verifying not working correctly

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom field on my SOOrder called "UsrProcessTypes," my goal is to have a pop up dialog when users choose this specific option "STCK." I tried the .Ask on a row selected on the base.documentcurrent on a row selected function and it was working correctly(testing purposes). When I applied it to the fieldverifying it was unsuccessful.

```
  protected virtual void SOOrder_UsrProcessTypes_FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
  {
    SOOrder row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
    SOOrderExt rowExt = sender.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(row);

    if(rowExt.UsrProcessTypes == "STCK")
    {
        if (Base.CurrentDocument.Ask("CONFIRM RECALCULTION",
                       "Confirm Recalculation",
                       MessageButtons.OK) != WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
        //
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue, I needed to use a rowupdating event instead of field verifying to achieve my goal.